# Recursion confusion QuickSort

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, quicksort

In solutions online people seem to use a recursive method that calls partition to get pivot index, but i don't understand why this recursive method doesn't work

```
def quickSort(arr, start, pivot_idx):
    if start>=pivot_idx:
       return
    
    i=start-1
    j=start
    
    while(j<pivot_idx):
        if arr[j]<arr[pivot_idx]:
            i+=1
            arr[j],arr[i]=arr[i],arr[j]
        j+=1
    arr[pivot_idx], arr[i+1]=arr[i+1], arr[pivot_idx]
    
    quickSort(arr, 0, i)
    quickSort(arr, i+2, len(arr)-1)
```

Edit:

I've been following this explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZaf_9IZCrc&t=136s .

A solution that works is changing 0 to start and len(arr)-1 to pivot_idx, but im not sure why that changes it

Comment: cause you're sorting the entire array every time (from `0` to `len(arr)-1`), instead of smaller subarrays

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not perform the recursive calls with the correct arguments. Each recursive call should get a range of the list that is a *subrange* of the current range. The current range is `start:pivot_idx+1`, so the recursive call should not pass on `0` as the start of the range, and not `len(arr)-1` as the end.

Correct it as follows:

```
quickSort(arr, start, i)  # start instead of 0
quickSort(arr, i+2, pivot_idx)  # pivot_idx instead of len(arr)-1
```